# HERE Maps Tile API CORS Errors at Random

Tags: here-api

I have tried a number of times to implement HERE Maps for our application. We have both web and desktop clients and so we can't lock it down to a specific domain. I'm using the map tiles REST API, and all works except that I get CORS errors at random. At most zoom levels it is about 10% of the tiles that fail to download, but at deeper zoom levels (14+), almost all tiles fail.

Why would some tiles load but other tiles fail with the same requests?  We have a Mapbox version that works flawlessly, and both use the Mercator projection and similar approach to tile specification.

**UPDATE**

Below you can see that most tiles downloaded OK but one did not:

[image: Network log from Chrome]

Following shows one of the successful requests:

[image: Success]

Next is a failed request:

[image]

Sometimes the same tile will load and other times not. This is at zoom level 10, and at 14+ things get much worse.

**UPDATE 2**

If I copy and paste two URIs into the browser address bar, one returns a tile and the other an error.  Both are identical except for the x and y tile numbers.  App ID and code are the same and in the correct order.  Examples are (with app id and code masked):

*https://4.base.maps.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/normal.day/16/12107/21196/256/png8?app_id=myID&app_code=mycode
https://4.base.maps.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/normal.day/16/12104/21195/256/png8?app_id=myID&app_code=mycode*

The error on the second one is:

*{"error":"Unauthorized","error_description":"This is not a valid app_id and app_code pair. Please verify that the values are not swapped between the app_id and app_code and the values provisioned by HERE (either by your customer representative or via http://developer.here.com/myapps) were copied correctly into the request."}*

It makes no sense why I would be getting seemingly random authorization errors.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the below for us to help you better: 1. Screenshots or other images or the exact error message you see
2. Hardware: DESKTOP | MOBILE | BOTH <target hardware(s)>
3. OS Version: WIN | MAC O/S | IPAD | IPHONE <operating system(s) the bug appeared on>
4. Browser and Version: IE | FIREFOX | CHROME | SAFARI <browser(s) the bug appeared on>
5. Steps to reproduce: (example code | instructions) <code, instructions - even when the behavior does not occur every time or has only occurred once>

Comment: I've updated my original post.

Comment: We tried the same but aren't able to reproduce the issue. can you check your source code if it sets the resolution based on pixel Ratio like shown: var pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;mapTileService.createTileLayer(
      'maptile',
      'normal.day',
      pixelRatio === 1 ? 256 : 512, parameters);

Comment: Seriously?  It's not a display issue.  As you "should be able to" see from my images, your service is refusing the request once in a while.  If all requests were refused I would check the code.  Since it seems to be at random, it is obviously not the code.  This is why I have given up on HERE Maps in the past, you have a broken system.  The same application works very well with Mapbox.  The only difference is the query.

Comment: HERE Developer Support, is it possible to pay for a telephone support incident to get to the bottom of this?

Comment: I added another update to my post showing two tile requests, one successful and one not.  The error is an authorization error even though the app ID and code are identical.  HERE Developer Support, can you please assist?

Answer (score 1):

The error you see is not due to CORS error. The 401 unauthorized response code, is either because you are using the wrong credentials or going over the quota for your credentials. In your case, it looks like you are over your quota(number of requests made).For any billing support questions, please email us at selfservesupport@here.com.

Comment: I'm experiencing something similar to what Tony described. I'm using my Freemium plan with sample code from the "Get Started "Guide (https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/dev_guide/topics/get-started.html) to test how here-api works. The problem is that it seems that vector.hereapi.com is randomly returning 401 responses every now and then.

For example, this request works fine:

https://vector.hereapi.com/v2/vectortiles/base/mc/13/4288/2773/omv?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.1.10.0&apikey=mykey&mv=in161

Comment: But then a moment later for the request below I get an error:
https://vector.hereapi.com/v2/vectortiles/base/mc/16/34313/22189/omv?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.1.10.0&apikey=mykey&mv=in161
The response I get from this request is:
 {"error":"Unauthorized","error_description":"ApiKey invalid. ApiKey not found."}

Of course, I substituted the real apikey with "mykey". In both requests the apikey is the same, the only difference is in which tile is requested. Can I please get some information to help me understand why it's happening?

Comment: In your comment above you mentioned it could also be related to account request quotas.. But I can get this random 401 error as I keep zooming into the maps even if I have made less than 100 HTTP requests within 24h. So neither "wrong apikey" nor "request quotas" explanation to this issue makes much sense.